# Error After adding Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads package

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, mono

**I'm facing this error on debug mode but this works fine on Release mode.**

> error: package com.google.android.gms.ads.purchase does not exist
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.purchase.InAppPurchaseListener AdvOSS.Droid
>   D:\AdvOSS\AdvOSS.Droid\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\com\google\android\gms\ads\purchase\InAppPurchaseListenerImplementor.java
>   8

Comment: clear bin and obj and clean build

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: yes it's solved.

Comment: thanks i already did this.
and its works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue solved by clearing bin and obj and rebuild the solution again.**